# How can I scan and read qr codes in swift UI

Tags: swift, swiftui, qr-code

I've searched a lot on this but have only found in UIKit and I am unable to convert this to SwiftUI

Answer (score 2):

There is no specific SwiftUI component for this purpose. But you can embed a UIKit component in a SwiftUI View and use that. 
Here is a nice example implementation of that.

https://github.com/twostraws/CodeScanner by Paul Hudson

Example usage also by Paul Hudson:

```swift
import CodeScanner
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isShowingScanner = false

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.isShowingScanner = true
        }) {
            Text("Show Scanner")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingScanner) {
            CodeScannerView(codeTypes: [.qr], simulatedData: "Some simulated data", completion: self.handleScan)
        }
    }

    private func handleScan(result: Result<String, CodeScannerView.ScanError>) {
       self.isShowingScanner = false
       switch result {
       case .success(let data):
           print("Success with \(data)")
       case .failure(let error):
           print("Scanning failed \(error)")
       }
    }
}
```